# Counterexample to the Hasse principle of the form $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + nt^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory, cubics

Selmer's cubic is a counterexample to the Hasse principle for ternary cubic forms.

We also know that the Hasse principle does not hold for quaternary cubic forms, as

$$
5x^3 + 12y^3 + 9z^3 + 10t^3
$$

represents zero over every completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, but does not represent zero over $\mathbb{Q}$.

My question is: Is there a known explicit counterexample to the Hasse principle of the form:

$$
x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + nt^3,
$$

for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$,
and would a demonstration that the Hasse principle *holds* for cubic forms of this form not trivially imply the "sums of three cubes conjecture"?

By this I of course mean that $x^3 + y^3 + z^3$ is universal over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for every $p \neq 3$, and hence represents $-n$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for every $p \neq 3$. The representation of $0$ by $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + nt^3$ over $\mathbb{Q}_3$ follows from the congruence conditions on $n$ mod 9, and thus the representation of $0$ by $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + nt^3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ follows from the Hasse principle.

I am, of course, aware that

$$\{
x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + nt^3 \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}
$$

is a very artificially constructed class of cubic forms.

Many thanks.

Comment: you might enjoy this. http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Schulze_Pillot_1982.pdf  related material at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/   Spinor exceptions are, well, a sort of weakness of Hasse.  The forms were discovered by Jones and Pall, just the one error corrected by Schulze-Pillot  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jones_Pall_1939.pdf   ; I hand wrote it there, journal page 191 , pdf page 31 of 32

Comment: your stuff is mostly in Mordell's book, page 88 has the 5,9,10,12 item and says it was Cassels and Guy (1966)

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for the references! I am aware that the quaternary counterexample is from [this paper](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0025579300003879). But what book by Mordell is it you are referring to?

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Diophantine_equations/QugvF7xfE-oC?hl=en